# HTML: elements are not aligning

Tags: html, css

I got this HTML page that has as a toolbar some buttons and a search filter.

```
<div class="topnav">
    <button>Add</button>
    <button>Delete</button>

    <button>Advanced Filters</button>
    <select id="select-items">
        <option value="uid">Uid</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="user_type">User type</option>
        <option value="last_login">Last login</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select-filter">
        <option>=</option>
        <option>></option>
        <option>>=</option>
        <option><</option>
        <option><=</option>
        <option>Starts with</option>
        <option>Contains</option>
        <option>Ends with</option>
    </select>
    <div class>
         <form onsubmit="search()" class="search-bar">
                     <input id="searchBar" class="input searchbar" type="text"
                            aria-autocomplete="list"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            style="height: 28.5px"
                     >
                    <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The way it looks right now:

[image]

I would like the search bar to be placed on the same row as the buttons, but it is placed below the first row for some reason. I tried using `float: right` and it still did not work. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Put `display: inline-block;` on the search div.

```css
.test {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <button>+</button>
    <button>-</button>

    <button>Adv</button>
    <select id="select-items">
        <option value="uid">Uid</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="user_type">User type</option>
        <option value="last_login">Last login</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select-filter">
        <option>=</option>
        <option>></option>
        <option>>=</option>
        <option><</option>
        <option><=</option>
        <option>Starts with</option>
        <option>Contains</option>
        <option>Ends with</option>
    </select>
    <div class=test>
         <form onsubmit="search()" class="search-bar">
                     <input id="searchBar" class="input searchbar" type="text"
                            aria-autocomplete="list"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            style="height: 28.5px; width: 12px"
                     >
                    <button><i class="fa fa-search">search</i>
                    </button>
                </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't style anything. so since everything is in one `container`, then just set the container's `display to flex` with `row direction`. and your main `container` here is `topnav`

```css
.topnav {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.topnav :nth-child(n){
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="topnav">
    <button>Add</button>
    <button>Delete</button>

    <button>Advanced Filters</button>
    <select id="select-items">
        <option value="uid">Uid</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="user_type">User type</option>
        <option value="last_login">Last login</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select-filter">
        <option>=</option>
        <option>></option>
        <option>>=</option>
        <option><</option>
        <option><=</option>
        <option>Starts with</option>
        <option>Contains</option>
        <option>Ends with</option>
    </select>
    <div class>
         <form onsubmit="search()" class="search-bar">
                     <input id="searchBar" class="input searchbar" type="text"
                            aria-autocomplete="list"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                     >
                    <button><i class="fa fa-search">search</i>
                    </button>
                </form>
    </div>
</div>
```